# Filtering RadGridView from a custom checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, telerik, radgridview

I have 2 column in RadGridView, i want to have my own checkboxes to filter RadGridView. So i disable the filter from the RadGridView :

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="AssetList_GridView"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        ShowGroupPanel="False" 
                        ColumnWidth="*" 
                        RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                        IsReadOnly="True">
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding assetName}" Header="Name" IsFilterable="False"/>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding assetType}" Header="Type" />
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Lets say i have 6 items in the GridView, with 3 different Types. So i create 3 checkboxes beside the GridView. How can i use my checkbox as filter in RadGridView? I don't wanna use the default filter from GridView because i want to have it besides the GridView all the time (not after i press the filter icon)